# IE<v9 Issue, jquery UI Radio button img in label won't trigger value change

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, button

I have several jquery ui radio buttons who's labels contain an image as well as text. In all other browsers, when you click the image, the button acts correctly (updates value). IE wil only update the value when you click the text. The button looks like it changes state, but the value doesn't change.

I've found others with the same issue, but no resolution that works. Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue. Click the image and check the value, then click the button outside the image and the value changes. Of course, you will need to look at it in ie.

http://jsfiddle.net/nJwbh/14/

Comment: in the fiddle, the button is a radio. Did you mean for it to be a checkbox instead?

Comment: radios. using buttonset() on a series of radios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE waits for focus to be lost on the input radio before dispatching the event. Try adding the following:

```
$("fire when").ready(function(e){
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('input:radio').click(function () {
            this.blur();
            this.focus();
        });
    }
});
```

---

Btw, if you are going to say you found others with the same issue but the solution didn't work, please add links to what you've tried already.

Comment: Found this bug ticket and I tried the suggestion, but it didn't work for me. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5979

Answer (score 2):

the solution given by OhCaN didn't work for me but the following did the trick

```
$("fire when").ready(function(e){
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $("input:radio").parent().find("img").click(function () {
            $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can be applied more generically and prevents skipping the click event on the label.  I found that if the click event was not triggered on the label, the jQuery UI button state did not update.

```
$("fire when").ready(function(){
     $("label img").click(function (e) {
        var label = $(this).parents("label");
        if (label) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            label.click();
            $("#" + label.attr("for")).triggerHandler("click");
        }
        return false;
    });
 });
```

I don't use $.browser so that the behavior is the same across all browsers.

JSFiddle Example
http://jsfiddle.net/rcollette/KfEmG/